# A pure CSS text link to video slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a pure css text link to video slider, within our Umbraco CMS.

I have very little movement on code I write as TinyMCE WYSIWYG will strip the majority of code out.

What I have done is created a base CSS slider and tried many click actions and the only one that seems to work is a standard HREF. So for example:

```
 

<!-- YouTube video - there's a few of these 'item*' -->

       <div class="item slide-in" id="item0">
 
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Wh8RzcQZr4?feature=oembed" 
              allowfullscreen="" width="410" height="231" frameborder="0"></iframe>
         
       </div>

<!-- End YouTube video -->

<!-- The link to call the video 'item*' -->

        <a href="#item1" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Cat link one</a>
        <br> <br>
        <a href="#item2" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Cat link two</a>

<!-- end link video 'item*' -->
```

The problem is that it has no option, but to work as a page anchor - which is really annoying me.

I'm not able to update anything else except the CMS interface. I've have capabilities to add JS in the head or footer of the document.

[Visit the jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Studio1st/Lhjy15ax/134/)

I can only add an onClick to an <a href... onclick=...>, but that still creates an on page anchor..

Any thoughts would be very much appriciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching an `<iframe>`'s `src` by an `<a>`nchor without any JavaScript is possible. Do the following:

1. Assign a `name` to `<iframe>`
2. Assign a `target` to `<a>` that value is `name` of `<iframe>`
3. Assign a `href` to `<a>` that value is the url of any valid youtube video.

Included suffix the url with `autoplay=1` if you want video to launch once the button is clicked.

Styled the link to blend into a button, since anchors irritate you?

**For some reason the videos aren't working in snippet, so for a live functioning example go to this** <kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>

### Demo

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RUlbTCjnX6E?ecver=1" target='yt'>1 Minute</a></button>
<button><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Wh8RzcQZr4?ecver=1" target='yt'>Cat Fails</a></button><br/>

<iframe name='yt' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Wh8RzcQZr4?feature=oembed" allowfullscreen width="410" height="231" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: That's hysterical - it's such an old method and so damn obvious... 

Thanks

Comment: IKR? Don't forget to click the "✔" and happy coding.